# What basic information do we need to help answer networking questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users

We get lots and lots and lots of questions like this:

[unable to ping to pi or ssh over wifi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/114777/5538)

> i unable to ping to RPi or SSH using Ubuntu Server 20.04. over wifi, but router assign ip to wlan0. when i plug the RPi with ethernet then wifi-ip is reachable for ping & ssh.
>
> How to resolve this issue? (i want RPi shall respond over wifi without plugin to ethernet)

**Please don't go and attack this;** it's been closed and presumably the OP either solved the problem or asked again, hopefully taking my comment there into account:

> Welcome. We need to be sure that what you are saying is correct. Paste the output of `ip addr` and `ip route` into your question when using wifi, and when using ethernet.

These (`ip addr` and `ip route`) are two things it is probably worthwhile to see for almost any "networking doesn't work properly" question.  A couple of other things would be `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and `ip addr`.  The former, though, is somewhat distro dependent.<sup>1</sup>

So my goal with this question is to get answers that *are* distro/OS specific; if you are an Arch user reading this and you feel there are some differences between that and Raspbian/RpiOS, please write it up here -- there does not need to be one ginormous answer to rule-them-all, a collection of targeted, succinct ones would be more useful.

These answers, or the whole Q&A, can then be linked in comments to questions like the one above.  This would hopefully save everyone some time, and they could also be linked in expanded tag info (eg., [wifi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi)).

Before that happens I will re-vamp this question to make it more on point for that audience (people who need the answers as opposed to those who can write them).

---

1. And all of them are linux specific.

Comment: I changed `route` to `ip route`. Although they provide much the same information the latter is probably clearer.

Comment: For SSh I would add the output of sudo systemctl status ssh

Answer (score 1):

You can have different specific answers, each belonging to an operating system, as you suggested. But I would prefer to manage this with tags. You can also link to the tag like to an answer but you are more free in the organization of the answer(s). The tags should be "reserved" and only moderators should be able to manage and assign them if it is possible. The tagged answers should be on the wiki so they can be easier modified by different specialists.

For example if you link to questions with tag [ping](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping) you present several Q&A. The idea is to manage, that are only answers shown which are duplicates of the question. So you do not have to touch the link you give to it in in a comment, but you are able to present some slightly different answers to match all (unclear) aspects of the question. And you can update them with better/newer information.

Comment: We don't have any special privileges WRT tags... I'm not sure I 100% understand you here...

Comment: @goldilocks I have updated the answer with an example.